# Overwrite value collection nested on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've a nested collection like this :

```
"package_detail": [
                {
                    "id": 229,
                    "package_id": 66,
                    "data_scoin_id": 210,
                    "unit_scoin_id": 3,
                    "created_at": "2020-01-16 21:51:18",
                    "updated_at": null,
                    "created_by": 1,
                    "updated_by": null,
                    "unit_scoin": {
                        "id": 3,
                        "unit_scoin": 1000,
                        "code_scoin": "SCOINAKHDLL2019                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ",
                        "description": "Seribu Scoin",
                        "rate_exchange": "Rp. 1.000",
                        "created_at": "2019-09-07 10:52:47",
                        "updated_at": null,
                        "created_by": null,
                        "updated_by": null
                    }
                },
```

I want to overwrite unit_scoin (parent) with unit_scoin (child)
I've been try to map and each the the **package_detail** index like this :

```
$packages = ScoinPackage::with('package_detail.unit_scoin')->get()
        ->map(function($d){
            $d->package_detail->each(function($dd) use (&$arr){
                $dd->unit_scoin = $dd->unit_scoin->unit_scoin;
            });

            return $d;
        });
```

But it was doesn't work, anyone can help me out ?

Comment: put the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

## SOLVED

conflict cause the object name is same.So first, save in a variable and unset it

```
$packages = ScoinPackage::with('package_detail.unit_scoin')->get()->map(function($d){
            $d->package_detail->map(function($dd){
                $unit = $dd->unit_scoin;
                unset($dd->unit_scoin); 
                $dd->unit_scoin = $unit->unit_scoin;
                return $dd;
            });
            return $d;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `map()` function to loop over the `package_details` as well. The each function won't return or change anything unless you pass the value by reference.

```
$packages = ScoinPackage::with('package_detail.unit_scoin')->get()
    ->map(function($d){
        $d->package_detail->map(function($dd) use (&$arr){
            $dd->unit_scoin = $dd->unit_scoin->unit_scoin;

            return $dd;
        });

        return $d;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `transform()` method, since `each()` just iterates over the collection without changing and `map()` one creates and returns new collection object (and doesn't modify initial one).

Something like this should do a trick:

```
$packages = ScoinPackage::with('package_detail.unit_scoin')->get()
    ->map(function($d){
        $d->package_detail->transform(function ($dd) {
            return $dd->unit_scoin = $dd->unit_scoin->unit_scoin;
        });

        return $d;
    });
```